# Android: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: java, android, export, manifest, dalvik

I am working on an Android Game and in order to allow people to report errors/crashes I recently added the first library to my project: [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#introduction)
It's a really helpful library which directly allows users to report crashes in different ways. The library is working fine so far.

It's still possible to upload the Game to my mobile phone directly and it (including ACRA) works successful (Debug Mode; Without ProGuard) but I **can not export the .APK file anymore**.
Always when I press the export Button following error comes up:

> Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

This is what I found out:

- The error is caused when there are two Classes/Packages with the same name (For example when LibaryX has Class org.a.b.c.Sample and LibaryY has class org.a.b.c.Sample aswell)
- **Different approaches which worked for some people** (So if you have the error yourself, make sure to test following things out):

A) Two Libraries have the exactly same package/class-> Delete the class in one of the Libraries

B) One Jar is detected twice because it's for example in the project source folder and in the Java Build Path Libraries aswell

C) Updating Proguard often fixes it aswell (Put the new Proguard jars in [Android SDK folder]\tools\proguard\lib)

D) Cleaning the Project also helped many people

I've tried all of these steps and even a few more (which I don't remember) but none of them worked for my case.

So I asked myself: "**What exactly causes the error?**" because before adding my first library (ACRA), everything was fine. I removed the library and implemented it again, step by step. Until one step caused the error.

So: Part of the ACRA setup was creating a new class which extends "android.app.Application". I've linked that Application class in my AndroidManifest.xml: Application -> Name=GameApplication.
The error appeared directly after the new GameApplication class being linked in the Manifest file. When I set 'Name' (In AndroidManifest.xml: Application) back to null, I can export my Game again.

Additional I found out, that the error can also be prevented by unticking the "Define an application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml" box, which disables my whole GameActivity class, which in turn handles the whole Game.

I think that the ACRA library itself is not the problem: I can successfully export the project with the ACRA library included - as long as the GameApplication class which initializes ACRA is not linked in the Android Manifest file.

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.black_ixx.manawar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.1" >
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" /><application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="org.black_ixx.goldenplosive.GameApp">
        <activity android:name="org.black_ixx.manawarlegends.ManaWarActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Edit:**

Just found the line which causes the error.

GameApp class:

```
package org.black_ixx.goldenplosive;

import org.acra.ACRA;
import org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode;
import org.acra.annotation.ReportsCrashes;
import org.black_ixx.manawar.R;
import android.app.Application;


@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", // will not be used
mailTo = "goldenplosivestudios@gmx.de",
mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
resToastText = R.string.acra_toast_text)

public class GameApp extends Application{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ACRA.init(this); //This line causes the error!!
    }
}
```

When I remove the ACRA.init-line I can export the file without any problems again but as I want to work with ACRA I have to keep it. But what exactly can be the problem there? :O

---

#### Solved

Just found the ProGuard section at the ACRA Github Page and fixed the Error. It was caused by missing lines in the proguard-project.txt.

Comment: Its better to describe the solution in the answer box provided and the tick "accepted". This is preferred to just editing something into the question text which does not cause the question to be marked as complete.